# GWT CellTable Custom Number Cell

Tags: gwt

GWT 2.5 -> I have created Custom NumberCell by extending EditTextCell , but it treats the amount value as String. I want to make column sort in that column but it sorts like String value.

Here is my code,

```
  package com.skit.compiere.client.widgets.fields;

    import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.BLUR;
    import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.DBLCLICK;
    import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.KEYDOWN;
     import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.BrowserEvents.KEYUP;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gwt.cell.client.EditTextCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.EventTarget;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.InputElement;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates.Template;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;
import com.google.gwt.text.shared.SafeHtmlRenderer;
import com.google.gwt.text.shared.SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer;

public class MyNumberEditCell extends EditTextCell 
 {
    Map<Object, MyNumberEditCell.ViewData> viewDataMap = new HashMap<Object, MyNumberEditCell.ViewData>();
     private SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer;
     public boolean editable = true;
        public String SelectedValue = null;
    ValueUpdater<String> supervalueup ;
     Element superparent ;
    NativeEvent superevent;
     ViewData viewdata;
    Context supercontext ;
    String supervalue ;
    Template template = GWT.create(Template.class);
        SafeHtmlBuilder superhtml = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
      Context ctx =null;
      String val;
      int i=-1;
      interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
            @Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\"></input>")
            SafeHtml input(String value);
          }



    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
         super.render(context, value, sb);
} 
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
        NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {

            if (DBLCLICK.equals(event.getType())) {
                super.onBrowserEvent(supercontext, superparent, supervalue, superevent, supervalueup);
        }
                    else if (BLUR.equals(event.getType())) {
                        // Commit the change. Ensure that we are blurring the input element and
                        // not the parent element itself.
                        EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
                        if (Element.is(eventTarget)) {
                          Element target = Element.as(eventTarget);
                          if ("input".equals(target.getTagName().toLowerCase())) {
                            commit(supercontext, superparent, viewdata, supervalueup);
                          }
                        }
                      }

            }
    public ViewData getviewData(Object key) {
        return (key == null) ? null : viewDataMap.get(key);
      }
    private void editEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
              ViewData viewData, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
            String type = event.getType();
            System.out.println(type);
            boolean keyUp = KEYUP.equals(type);
            boolean keyDown = KEYDOWN.equals(type);
//          int keyCodes = event.getKeyCode();
//         if(event.getKeyCode()==32){
//               event.preventDefault();
//               return;
//           }
            if (keyUp || keyDown) {
              int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

               if ( keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER ||keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) {
                // Commit the change.
                commit(context, parent, viewData, valueUpdater);
              } 

              else if (keyUp && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) {
                // Cancel edit mode.
                String originalText = viewData.getOriginal();
                if (viewData.isEditingAgain()) {
                  viewData.setText(originalText);
                  viewData.setEditing(false);
                } else {
                  setviewData(context.getKey(), null);
                }
                cancel(context, parent, value);
              } else {
                // Update the text in the view data on each key.
//                if(event.getKeyCode()==32){
//                    viewdata.setText(viewdata.getText()+" ");
//                    viewdata.setEditing(true);
//                 }
                updateViewData(parent, viewData, true);
              }
            } 

          }
    @Override
    public boolean isEditing(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
         SafeHtmlBuilder safehtml = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        return false;

    }
    private void cancel(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
        clearInput(getInputElement(parent));
        setValue(context, parent, value);
      }
    private native void clearInput(Element input) /*-{
    if (input.selectionEnd)
      input.selectionEnd = input.selectionStart;
    else if ($doc.selection)
      $doc.selection.clear();
  }-*/;

    private InputElement getInputElement(Element parent) {
        return parent.getFirstChild().<InputElement> cast();
      }

    private String updateViewData(Element parent, ViewData viewData,
              boolean isEditing) {
            InputElement input = (InputElement) parent.getFirstChild();
            String value = input.getValue();
            viewData.setText(value);
            viewData.setEditing(isEditing);
            return value;
          }

    private void commit(Context context, Element parent, ViewData viewData,
              ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
            String value = updateViewData(parent, viewData, false);
            clearInput(getInputElement(parent));
            setValue(context, parent, value);
            if (valueUpdater != null) {
              valueUpdater.update(value);
            }
          }
    public void setValue(Context context, Element parent, String value) {
        SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        renderFields(context, value, sb);
        parent.setInnerSafeHtml(sb.toSafeHtml());
      }
    private void renderFields(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        this.renderer = SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance();
        Object key = context.getKey();
        ViewData viewData = getviewData(key);
        if (viewData != null && !viewData.isEditing() && value != null
            && value.equals(viewData.getText())) {
          clearViewData(key);
          viewData = null;
        }

        String toRender = value;
        if (viewData != null) {
          String text = viewData.getText();
          if (viewData.isEditing()) {
            /*
             * Do not use the renderer in edit mode because the value of a text
             * input element is always treated as text. SafeHtml isn't valid in the
             * context of the value attribute.
             */
            sb.append(template.input(value));
            return;
          } else {
            // The user pressed enter, but view data still exists.
            toRender = text;
          }
        }

        if (toRender != null && toRender.trim().length() > 0) {
          sb.append(renderer.render(toRender));
        } else {
          /*
           * Render a blank space to force the rendered element to have a height.
           * Otherwise it is not clickable.
           */
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("\u00A0");
        }

    }
    public void setviewData(Object key, ViewData viewData) {
        if (key == null) {
          return;
        }

        if (viewData == null) {
          clearViewData(key);
        } else {
          viewDataMap.put(key, viewData);
        }
      }
    static class ViewData {

        private boolean isEditing;

        /**
         * If true, this is not the first edit.
         */
        private boolean isEditingAgain;

        /**
         * Keep track of the original value at the start of the edit, which might be
         * the edited value from the previous edit and NOT the actual value.
         */
        private String original;

        private String text;

        /**
         * Construct a new ViewData in editing mode.
         *
         * @param text the text to edit
         */
        public ViewData(String text) {
          this.original = text;
          this.text = text;
          this.isEditing = true;
          this.isEditingAgain = false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
          if (o == null) {
            return false;
          }
          ViewData vd = (ViewData) o;
          return equalsOrBothNull(original, vd.original)
              && equalsOrBothNull(text, vd.text) && isEditing == vd.isEditing
              && isEditingAgain == vd.isEditingAgain;
        }

        public String getOriginal() {
          return original;
        }

        public String getText() {
          return text;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
          return original.hashCode() + text.hashCode()
              + Boolean.valueOf(isEditing).hashCode() * 29
              + Boolean.valueOf(isEditingAgain).hashCode();
        }

        public boolean isEditing() {
          return isEditing;
        }

        public boolean isEditingAgain() {
          return isEditingAgain;
        }

        public void setEditing(boolean isEditing) {
          boolean wasEditing = this.isEditing;
          this.isEditing = isEditing;

          // This is a subsequent edit, so start from where we left off.
          if (!wasEditing && isEditing) {
            isEditingAgain = true;
            original = text;
          }
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
          this.text = text;
        }

        private boolean equalsOrBothNull(Object o1, Object o2) {
          return (o1 == null) ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you extend the [NumberCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/NumberCell.html) instead?

Comment: On doubleClick of TextCell only i am rendering the NumberCell to achieve non editable of NumberCell before clicking on it.